# Cognito Hosted UI with custom domain

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito

I'm building my first website with ASP.NET Core. I'm authenticating users using Amazon Cognito hosted UI. I've set up my Cognito user pool and I added Cookie and OpenID authentications to my application.

I've set up the allowed callback URLs to: `https://localhost:7063/signin-oidc`

When debugging my application, when I try to access a page that needs `[Authorize]`, and the user is not logged in, the Cognito hosted UI is displayed. After successful login the page is displayed correctly.

While debugging every thing works as expected.

Next step I hosted my website with a custom domain I bought. I modified my cognito to use the custom domain for the hosted UI, I made a few tests, in debug mode, and the hosted UI with my domain is working. Next I added a new allowed callback URL: `https://mydomain/signin-oidc` Now I have two allowed callbacks, one for localhost, when I'm debugging, and one for the domain.

When I test the website, just like I did when I was debugging, this time the hosted UI display an error: `https://auth.mydomain.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=184287eaqfj2qeigjkb7uu5h1`
"An error was encountered with the requested page."

It looks like there is no callback URL for the request. I'm not sure if I'm not allowing correctly the URL for my custom domain like I did for the localhost.

I followed this tutorial for setting up Cognito and my application https://coderjony.com/blogs/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using-amazon-cognito, the only thing I changed was adding a new allowed URL to the hosted UI and changing the localhost:7063 for "mydomain".

Am I missing something? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Newbie mistake, just changed `https://example/signin-oidc` for `https://example.com/signin-oidc` and it's working.